# Reversing the effect of \nopagenumbers in plain TeX

Tags: page-numbering, plain-tex

I'm happy with Plain TeX's page-numbering format, except that I want to turn it off for the first few pages of my book.  I can do this with the `\nopagenumbers` macro, but is there a macro with the opposite effect, to make the page numbers reappear later?  Or do I have to manually re-establish the default footer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick look at `\nopagenumbers` shows

```
> \nopagenumbers=macro:
->\footline {\hfil }.
```

while `\showthe\footline` yields

```
> \hss \tenrm \folio \hss .
```

Thus the simplest solution is by hand

```
\def\pagenumbers{\footline{\hss\tenrm\folio\hss}}
```

You could of course save the existing definition using something like

```
\newtoks\savedfootline
\savedfootline\expandafter{\the\footline}
```

and restore with

```
\footline\expandafter{\the\savedfootline}
```

or use a group within your document: `\begingroup` before `\nopagenumbers` and `\endgroup` after.

Note that whatever approach you use, make sure you force a new page, for example

```
\begingroup
  \nopagenumbers
  <content>
  \vfil
  \eject
\endgroup
```

Comment: Why `toks` and not `let`?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides You can't `\let` here as that will still point to the same toks, not the _content_ of the toks (same for all registers). I could save the content in a macro in this case, but in general you can't be sure of that so best practice is to save toks in toks, not macros.